# Panoramic image in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server

How can we post a Panoramic image in SharePoint with features to move it in a 360 view by the user? Is there any OOB option available or implement it using some jquery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try below js:

```
$('.pan-wrap').append('<div class="play">play</div>');

var hoverInterval;

function doStuff() {
  $(this).animate({
    'background-position-x': '+=5%',
  }, 250, 'linear');
}

$(function() {
  $('.pan-wrap').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).empty();
      hoverInterval = setInterval($.proxy(doStuff, this), 250);
    },
    function() {
      // stop calling doStuff
      $(this).append('<div class="play">play</div>');
      clearInterval(hoverInterval);
      $('this').animate({
        'background-position-x': '+=5%',
      }, 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
    });
});
```

You can also try to use below panorama viewers:

Pannellum is a lightweight, free, and open source panorama viewer for the web:

https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum

Display your panorama photos on your site with this plugin(Panorama Viewer):

https://github.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer